# Can IBOutlets be used in App Delegate to access Document windows?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Forgive me if this is obvious, but I'm very new to Cocoa and Objective-C.

I have a very simple Text Editor app that has two windows created using Interface Builder. One for the text content, and another window with various controls and an "Enter full screen" button.

I have an IBOutlet called myWindow defined in the App Delegate, linked to the text editor window. I use:

```
[self.myWindow togglefullscreen]
```

in the App Delegate to enter full screen mode when "Enter full screen" button is pressed on the other window.

Now, I am trying to convert my application into a Document Based Application.

My question is: how do I access the current Document's window so I can call togglefullscreen on it, from within the App Delegate? Is this even possible/elegant?

Interface builder won't let me connect the IBOutlet in the App Delegate to the Document window in Document.xib which I guess makes sense as there could be multiple instances of it.

Another question that stems from this is, should this full-screen functionality be implemented in the Document class, and should the "Full Screen" button be on the Document window itself (as only one document will ever be full-screen)?

Any ideas would be much appreciated :-)

John

Answer (score 0):

An NSDocument (sub-class) can have more than one window associated with it. Your NSDocument sub-class can access NSDocument's windowControllers property to get an NSArray of windowControllers (IIRC back to front order) and ask each one for it's associated window (property).

Comment: I managed this finally by simply getting hold of the App's main window, which is the active document window:

    [[NSApp mainWindow] togglefullscreen:self];

Regards,

John